# Apache Beam GCP Dataflow Suggestion Implementation

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running apache beam pipeline on GCP dataflow.
The dataflow pipeline suggests following item

A fusion break can be inserted after the following transforms to increase parallelism: ReadFromGCS/Match All/Match filepatterns/ParMultiDo(Match). The transforms had the following output-to-input element count ratio, respectively: 1006307.

my pipeline looks something like this

```py
        PCollection<String> records =  p.apply("ReadFromGCS", TextIO.read().from(options.getInput())
                .withHintMatchesManyFiles());

        PCollection<Document> documents = records.apply("ConvertToDocument", ParDo.of(new ProcessJSON(options.getBatch())));
        // Write to MongoDB using ParDo transform sink
        documents.apply("WriteToMongoDB", MongoDbIO.write()
                .withUri("mongodb+srv://"+options.getMongo())
                .withDatabase(options.getDatabase())
                .withCollection(options.getCollection())
                .withBatchSize(options.getBatchSize()));
```

my input is a gcs bucket of pattern 'gs://test-bucket/test/*.json' which contains million json files
I want to understand what does the suggestion mean and how do I increase parallelism as suggested my dataflow in my case.

I tried this documentation but could not figure out how to solve this
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-dataflow-insights?&_ga=2.162468924.-1096227812.1671933466#high-fan-out

attaching screenshot
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxy7R.png)

Comment: Apache beam has an "options" configuration file https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.0.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html   while it is not part of a server there are ways of managing assigning  the individual number of worker threads of the JVM and CPU.   https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options

Comment: How does this help in solving above suggestion?

Comment: You said   ..."tried this documentation ( Google data flow docs ) but could not figure out how to solve this"...  and You also said ..."want to understand what does the suggestion mean and how do I implement parallelism"...   Of "how" , as the others of us do, you can read it!!! And read the java API docs about "concurrency" and worker thread management too!   So it means how you manage JVM threads for the CPU(s) in Apache beam and Google data flow.

Comment: ....and if you have some time CPU cores and NUMA Non-uniform memory access and SMP  shared-memory multiprocessing 
 may be of some help depending the machines hardware.

Comment: HEY! did you get "a suggestion message from the runtime"? ( The dataflow pipeline suggests following item... ).  See API docs for static class    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey and  static class org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupByKey.   It's about not allowing the pipeline to group results and operations together onto the one job by auto optimizing. There appears to be some config setting optional for the runtime also.

Comment: One final problem, if you are UPDATE into a database it may also be wise to queue the results into a transaction rather than get at the database per job if as you seem to show there are over a million result elements!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [Fusion Optimization](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/pipeline-lifecycle#fusion_optimization) for some background information on how to enforce/prevent a fusion.

A very common way is to have [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/java/aggregation/groupbykey/) if there is some natural way to group things, or use operations such as [Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Reshuffle.ViaRandomKey.html) if you want to just spread evenly.

Comment: I did try to reshuffle but it did not have any effect
I am facing same issue.

Comment: Apart threadpools and itsAPI , have you checked in the OS how many cores are given over to the JVM? And  are there any direct API controls in beam and data flow. I've been noticing to test such heavy concurrent processing   for servlets and pages requires a Dev machine with e.g.  32 cores before any real world test attempt at triggering a bottleneck of concurrent work.

Comment: Also, just noticed the typo in early comment should contain.. read about "side inputs" (job fusion by worker threads thread optimizing control) by re feeding into another org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo in it's API doc

Comment: Hazard a guess, Google Data flow belongs on its own separate machine with a minimalist OS for vast job quantities to allow the high level of processing with concurrency to occur rational thread configuration and hardware resource safety! e.g. 32 CPU cores and all software configured from the base up with the machine containing OS and thereabout Google data flow only.

Comment: As the previous comment, I do not believe you will get anywhere until the database call is removed from your code and the database collects through an intermediary program looking for completed separately indexed results stored in a folder. The G dataflow program has a 30gb default disk space requirement and the config suggests a special tempdir and special jobs folder. DB connections require timeout unlike standard read write waitable network or thread streams.